# python can't open file... [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: bash, python-2.7, command-line, cygwin, execute

First, it works on my work computer, but doesn't work on my home desktop.
Second, I've explored several previous answers, with no luck. Perhaps I just didn't read the ONE that has my solution.

I want to run an executable python script from anywhere (it takes one string argument). My solution is to use a bash alias in .bashrc:

I have tried several variants:

```
alias tlog="~/projects/tlog/tlog.py"
alias tlog="/c/cyg/home/<my_username>/projects/tlog/tlog.py"
alias tlog="C:\\cyg\\home\\<my_username>\\projects\\tlog\\tlog.py"
alias tlog='"/c/cyg/home/<my_username>/projects/tlog/tlog.py"'
alias tlog='"C:\\cyg\\home\\<my_username>\\projects\\tlog\\tlog.py"'
alias tlog="python ~/projects/tlog/tlog.py"
```

None of them work, the respective outputs are:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/home/<my_username>/projects/tlog/tlog.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/c/cyg/home/<my_username>/projects/tlog/tlog.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
bash: C:cyghome<my_username>projectstlogtlog.py: command not found
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/c/cyg/home/<my_username>/projects/tlog/tlog.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
bash: C:\cyg\home\<my_username>\projects\tlog\tlog.py: command not found
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/home/<my_username>/projects/tlog/tlog.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So for a sanity check, I did this:

```
$ cd ~/projects/tlog
$ ls
logs  prev_log_date  tlog.py
```

Yep it's there... so does it run?

```
$ ./tlog.py "TEST"
yadda yadda it worked
```

Yep, so now:

```
$ ~/projects/tlog/tlog.py "TEST"
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/home/<my_username>/projects/tlog/tlog.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Well... what about

```
$ more ~/projects/tlog/tlog.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
tlog - tlog docstring
"""
...rest of file...
```

Yep, it's still there. Anyone got an answer for me?
For reference:

```
$ ls -la
...more files...
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 <my_username> <my_username> 6376 Nov 10 17:59 tlog.py
$ cd ..
$ ls -la
...more files...
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 <my_username> <my_username> 0 Nov 10 17:59 tlog
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with your aliases, but you could add it to your path.  `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/projects/tlog`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you use windows-based python, not cygwin based python

Check for cygwin python installed

```
ls /bin/python*
```

if you do not have cygwin python, install it.

If you already have cygwin python installed, then check your PATH variables -- cygwin /bin/ folder must go before windows python folder.

If you really need to use windows python from cygwin... read a lot about 'windows python from cygwin' -- there are tons of glitches, special situations and unpredicted behaviors

Also, you can try such alias: (cannot check it myself)

```
alias tlog="cmd.exe C:\\Python27\\python.exe -i C:\\cyg\\home\\<my_username>\\projects\\tlog\\tlog.py"
```